# How can I read .dat file separating "::" in R

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a text file with "::" separator.
When I read this file like below.

```
tmp <- fread("file.dat", sep="::")  
tmp <- read.table("file.dat", sep="::")
```

There is a `'sep' must be 'auto' or a single character` or `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte` error message.

How can I read this file?

Comment: or much less lovely than Richards suggestion.. something along the lines of  `read.table(text=gsub("::", " ", readLines(yourfile)))`

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
fread("cat file.dat | tr -s :", sep = ":")
```

`fread()` allows a system call in its first argument.  This one uses `tr -s`, which is a "squeeze" command, replacing the repetitions of `:` with single occurrences of that character.

With this call, `fread()` may even recognize the `sep` argument automatically, eliminating the need to name it.

Using the same concept, another way you could go (with an example file "x.txt") is to do

```
writeLines("a::b::c", "x.txt")
read.table(text = system("cat x.txt | tr -s :", intern = TRUE), sep = ":")
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  a  b  c
```

I'm not sure how this translates to Windows-based systems.

Comment: You can use `shell()` in place of `system()` on Windows machines.  However, I'm not sure exactly what the commands would be.  Same with `fread()` I think, just replace with bash commands (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: I use on windows. but there is an error(execution failed with error code 255).  fread() and read.table using shell().

Comment: @Rokmc1050 - I'm trying to get you an answer for Windows, just not sure yet.  You could probably use user20650's suggestion from the comments below your question.